# Backspace doesn't work inside running bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm running very simple script which reads line by line and prints entered line back to terminal:

```
while read CMD; do
    echo $CMD
done
```

It works fine, but when I'm trying to edit line with `backspace` character it prints `^?`instead of deleting character. And when I press `Ctrl` + `backspace` the output is `^H`. How could this behavior be fixed so `backspace` removes character instead of adding these characters?
I tried `stty erase '^?'` command but not successfully.

Comment: Please note 16.10 reached the end of its support cycle last month. You should upgrade to 17.04 as soon as possible.

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use? `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm using `gnome-terminal` ver. 3.20.2

Comment: I suggest to replace `read CMD` by `read -e CMD`.

Comment: what is the output of `stty -a | grep erase`, is that `^?` ?

Comment: @AFSHIN yes, true. It's `^?`.

Comment: try `terminator` instead of `gnome-terminal` . Its working as expected

Comment: @Cyrus Why wouldn't you post your proposal as a full answer? Adding `-e` switch to `read` command activates the usage of GNU Readline to obtain the input. With that switch Backspace erases the previous character without producing `^H` in the input line (despite the setting `Control-H` as a Backspace sequence in Gnome terminal's properties).

Comment: @whtyger: It does not seem to have helped vrom911 or Shersh.

Comment: @whtyger this worked for this script. In my real situation I have input from program, which doesn't call read. I have no opportunity to change the program script, this was just an example which represented  my issue. Is there any global settings where I can have this configurations done for all input?

Comment: @Cyrus My Backspace works as I want — it deletes last character always, even for this script from question  without `-e` option. But on @vrom911's machine it's not the case. I wonder why it happens and where this can be configured.

Comment: MAy I ask why you want this setup? Do you want to debug something? Do you want to see which command is running in your script? What is this all about?

Comment: @s1mmel I want to be able to use backspace and other keys to edit the text I'm enter in program input. My program requires some long text as input so without backspace it's really easy to mess up.

Comment: Hmh, why dont you put it in a text file first and feed it to the script, like so

./myscript.sh < input.txt

You can even put \n returns into the txt file. This would be equivalent to a user tayping in the text in the console.

Comment: @s1mmel Because I can't change the insides of the program. It requires the text interactively. But the program itself is not my problem actually. My problem is that I can't use backspace in input mode of any bash program in my terminal.

Comment: If adding `-e` switch to the `read` command works well, then I guess one should look for a way to have bash use `readline` by default, for any input action (not only `read` bash builtin). I wouldn´t know how to do this.

Comment: @sancho.s I had the same idea, but didn't find the way to do this. Still hope to get an answer here.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there are many ways to represent a backspace, but the `read` command doesn't understand all of them. You should be able to configure what exactly is sent when pressing the <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> key in your terminal emulator's settings.

Assuming you're using `gnome-terminal` as emulator, open the **Edit** manu and click on **Profile preferences**. Switch to the **Compatibility** tab and you should get these options:

[image: gnome-terminal → profile preferences → compatibility]

Now you can change the **Backspace key generates:** setting. You have these five options below available to chose from. I added in braces how they behave on my system:

- Automatic (works)
- Control-H (prints `^H` instead)
- ASCII DEL (default, works)
- Escape sequence (prints `^[[3~` instead)
- TTY Erase (works)

Comment: Currently I have ASCII DEL. I have tried all 5 options but none of them fixed the issue.

Comment: That is strange. Can you tell my what `type read` says and what shell/version `$SHELL --version` reports?

Comment: I know it is strange. I tried to google my problem a lot but didn't find solution that works for me.
`type read` says `read is a shell builtin`.
and
`$SHELL --version` says
`GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, using bash in Gnome-Terminal.

Note that on the command line, the backspace works as expected, but when my program (a simple TCP socket based chat client) is reading from stdin, the `backspace` character prints (echoes back to the screen) `^?`instead of deleting the last character.

Use `# stty icanon` to allow the "canonical (cooked) mode".  See some explanation here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal

Some more background to my problem/solution: I had a problem where I need to paste more than 4k characters. And during that research, I was led to the above link.  I used `# stty -icanon` to disable the 4k limit, but lost the ability to use backspace (erase).